# GRANT PRIVILEGES command from mysql server on laptop not affecting database hosted on online server

Tags: mysql, database, cpanel

I am trying to grant privileges to a user on my mysql database hosted on an online web hosting service so that I can further establish a connection to an Android project.

I have downloaded the mysql server on my laptop & have completed all the root setup steps.

I have included my IP address on the Remote MySQL page of my cPanel.

Things I have tried:

1. I tried the below command on my terminal along with other slight modification commands mentioned in other answers.

   mysql> CREATE USER 'indipare_test2'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 
   'password';
   Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

   mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'indipare_test2'@'localhost';
   Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

   mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
   Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

Then went on to 'Check privileges' option against my database in cPanel. It said "No privileges".

2. Without creating a new user Granted privilege to a user present on my online server through my terminal window. Still "No privileges".
3. Tried this command on the SQL section of database section in phpmyadmin on cPanel. Still no success.

What am I missing here? My end goal is that once it starts working the below php file present on the public_html folder of filemanager of cPanel start giving "Connection Successful". 
I have a domain on which I am opening the below php file.

```
<?php

$host=“localhost”;
$user=“user_name”;
$password=“password”;
$db=“db_name”;

$con=mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$db);

if(!$con)
{
echo "Connection not happening";
die(mysqli_connect_error());
}

else{
echo "<br><h3>Connection Success</h3>";
}
?>
```

Comment: You should have 1 row affected and not 0 rows

Comment: Are you using cPanel?

Comment: Are you sure your host allows incoming database connections? Most hosts block these for security purposes.